# Не подключается шрифт... css

Tags: css, шрифты

Вот код, ../ тоже пробовал. Не работает...

Вот код:

```
@font-face {
font-family:'Proxima Nova';
     src: url('/fonts/proximanova-regular.eot');
     src: local('☺'), url('/fonts/proximanova-regular.woff') format('woff'), 
     url('/fonts/proximanova-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), 
     url('/fonts/proximanova-regular.svg') format('svg');
     font-weight: 400;
     font-style: normal;
```

Comment: какая структура папок?

Comment: в fonts лежат шрифты, сразу, без доп папок.

Comment: где расположен css ?

Comment: Лежит в папке css.

Comment: получается папка css и fonts на одном уровне? Если так - тогда ../fonts/yourFonts

Comment: url('../fonts/proximanova-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), так не работает... В этом и весь идиотизм. Файл стилей естественно подключен...

Comment: покажите, как вы выводите шрифты или дайте ссылку на сайт производите подключение

Comment: /*Шрифты
=======================*/
@font-face {
 font-family:'Proxima Nova';
 src: url('../fonts/proximanova-regular.eot');
 src: local('☺'), url('../fonts/proximanova-regular.woff') format('woff'), 
 url('../fonts/proximanova-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), 
 url('../fonts/proximanova-regular.svg') format('svg');
 font-weight: 400;
 font-style: normal;
}

Answer (score 2):

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova Regular';
  src: url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  }

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova Semibold';
  src: url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Semibold.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Semibold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Semibold.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Semibold.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  }

@font-face {
font-family: 'Proxima Nova Black';
src: url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Black.eot');
src: url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Black.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Black.woff') format('woff'),
url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Black.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-display: swap;
}

@mixin reg {
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova Regular',sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}
@mixin bold {
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova Semibold',sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

@mixin black {
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova Black',sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

вот пример того, как это реализовано у меня через препроцессор sass, может быть поможет. Перед папкой fonts у меня .. потому что стили лежат тоже в папке, сначала нужно из нее выйти, чтобы войти в папку fonts